# Get parsefloat number from paragraph text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the float number 9.5 but I am getting 95. How can I solve this?

```js
$('p.text-decoration').on('click',function(){
      var getTxtNum = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')
      var getFloatNum = parseFloat(getTxtNum)
      $('input.items_number').val(getFloatNum)
      console.log('test'+getFloatNum)                                               
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" size="3" class="items_number" value="0.0">
<p class="mt-3 mb-3 text-decoration cursor-pointer">Suggested ad rate 9.5%</p>
```

Comment: Your replace command is removing the period. Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/9bsjeLt3/ (note that you shouldn't use variable names starting with `get`; names like that make sense for functions that are actually getting something, not so much for variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RegEx `string.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')` in replace is removing the period, you should do this: `string.replace(/[^0-9.]/gi, '')`

```js
$('p.text-decoration').on('click',function(){
      var getTxtNum = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9.]/gi, '')
      var getFloatNum = parseFloat(getTxtNum)
      $('input.items_number').val(getFloatNum)
      console.log('test'+getFloatNum)                                               
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" size="3" class="items_number" value="0.0">
<p class="mt-3 mb-3 text-decoration cursor-pointer">Suggested ad rate 9.5%</p>
```